# How control the embedded sensors on smartphones via Matlab

Tags: android, matlab, usb, signal-processing, sensors

I would like acquire the output of the several instruments embedded in my Android mobile device via Matlab, using the USB connector.

I know that there are a lot of applications that allow me of save this data in the my device and, in a second time, move these file to my computer for processing here.

But I'm looking for a system where the query start from Matlab, that asks to a single sensor, e.g., photo camera, video camera, accelerometer, gyroscope, GPS, to send its output for a post-processing.

I don't ask a solution "all inclusive", of course, but if Matlab is able to dialogue with system like Arduino, Raspberry PI, Lego NXT and so on, is possible there is also a way for Android.

Thank you in advanced,
*Giacomo*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I teach (to my students) in such cases: "Google is your friend.", but I don't remember ever this lesson for me.

In the Matlab File Exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40876) there is a free toolbox for analyzing output data.

Of course, in the smartphone must be installed an application: SensorUdp (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ac.ehime_u.cite.sasaki.SensorUdp).

Matlab and the device must be in the same network, Matbab provides an IP address and a port for communication.

Enjoy,
*Giacomo*

Comment: PS This toolbox works with Android and iPhone or iPad. More details in the MathWorks page.